# CFG for constituent tree of As Bs and as and bs

Tags: grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, context-free-grammar, lexical-analysis, formal-languages

I have the following constituent tree, and I am confused on how to find the context-free grammar as I am not used to these notations of As and Bs.

```
                                  S
                                /   \
                              A      A
                            /   \    |  
                           A     B   a 
                         /   \   |
                        A     B  b
                        |     |
                        a     b
```

I thought of the following *CFG*:

```
S -> AA
A -> AB
A -> a
B -> b
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Your problem in understrained.  A language is defined by an arbitrary set of strings.  You show only one string here:  abab.   If that *is* the language, then S -> abab; and S -> XX;   X->ab;  are two perfectly valid different CFGs that work.  How will you choose?  If abab is not the only instance of the langauge, then you don't have enough information to define any mechanism for generating the language, let alone a CFG.

Comment: I think what you have done is very reasonable. If this is the only information you are given, you can infer the grammar for which this parse tree was generated has at least the terminals a and b, at least the nonterminals S, A and B, and at least the productions you've shown. Sure, the language may have other grammars that generate it, but they wouldn't have this parse tree if they didn't have at least what you show.